# scrolling issue with huge points of stackedbar graph

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, charts, mschart

I have chart with multiple chart areas and every area contain a bunch of series that need to be updated with scrolling, all chart areas working well except the one below , it takes alot of resources from the memory i think and not scrolling smoothly.

I want to achieve this chart area effectively with smooth scrolling

[image]

i achieved same results using stacked bar graph, i added the points from data table, here is how the data table looks like

[image]

And as i know displaying only the portion that is needed is certainly the option the takes least resources and time,
so here is the code i use to add my points from data table

```
       private void GraphDemo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           System.Drawing.Rectangle workingRectangle =
           System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
           this.chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(workingRectangle.Width - 50, 1000);

           scroller = new VScrollBar();
           scroller.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
           croller.Maximum = 6000 - windowSize;  //windowSize = 180;
           scroller.LargeChange = 180;

           scroller.Scroll += scroller_Scroll;

        }


   void scroller_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
   {    

          for (int s = 0; s < chart.Series.Count; s++)
          {
            LoadCore.chart.Series[s].Points.Clear();
          }



        for (float ii = 0; ii < dt.Rows.Count; ii++)
        {
        row = dt.Rows[(int)ii];
        ts11 = Convert.ToDouble(row.ItemArray[0]) + 1;  //top.value column + 1
        ts12 = Convert.ToDouble(row.ItemArray[1]);      //base.value column

          for  (double t = LoadCore.ts11; t <= LoadCore.ts12; t++)
          {
           //k is the index no. of each series column
           for (int k = 2; k <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; k++)
              {
                if (scroller.Value < t)
                  {
                     if (scroller.Value + windowSize > t) //windowSize = 180;
                        {
                           //tempindex1 is the index of specific row value at specific base.value columnn
                          chart.Series[Convert.ToString(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName)].Points.AddXY(t, dt.Rows[tempIndex1][k]);
                          chart.Series[Convert.ToString(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName)]["PointWidth"] = "1";

                         }
                   }
               }
          }
        }
    }
```

With the above code i still can not scroll smoothly and i think it's because of the huge number of points needed to be added with the portion of 180 (window size), ...

so my question is there an alternative effective way to achieve the first image with smooth scrolling?.

should i use any other types of graph instead of stacked bar graph ? what is it?

Comment: How many points do you have in total? Maybe you can afforf to keep them all in the chart without paging after all? Did you try? But adding 180 points shouldn't cause a lag.

Comment: you can not say it's 180 points
it's 180 bar and each bar contains 9 or 10 series means nine points at each bar, because it's stacked bar , i can not escape the zero or null points 
it will cause mess in the bar 

my table first value 
top.value = 10

and last base value will be 
base.value = 6000

you can say the total bars equal 5990 bar int he chartarea

5990 * 9(series) = 53910 .... that's roughly sum for the total points of chartarea

i tied to add them without scroll , that was super lag , also as i said i have another chart areas in the graph containg lines and step lines

Comment: Typically, when working with large amounts of data like this, you want to make a datasource with all your points and set the chart's datasource to this.  Manually looping through all the points and adding them individually is what is causing all the lag.

Comment: can you post a hint about how i can make the datasource?

Comment: Make a class that contains a value for x and a value for y.  Make a List<classtype> and add all your points to the list.  Set the chart datasource to your list.